Expressing integral based on the change of variables in double integral
Let B be the region in the first quadrant bounded by the curves $xy=1$,$xy=3$,$x^2−y^2=1$, and $x^2−y^2=4.$
Evaluate $\iint_{B} (x^2 + y^2 ) dx dy$ using the change of
variables $u=x^2−y^2$,$v=xy.$
The Jacobian is  $J = 2(x^2+y^2)$.
But I have a difficulty to express the new transformed integral .It must be $$\iint_{D^*}f (x(u, v), y(u, v)) J dudv$$
$$ \iint_{D^*} ?  2(x^2+y^2) dudv$$
What is placed in the $f(x(u, v), y(u, v))$ in the solutions book is $1/2$.But I can understand why? How can I  express $x^2+y^2$ based on $u=x^2−y^2,v=xy$ ?
is $$ \iint_{D^*} \frac{x^2+y^2}{  2(x^2+y^2)} dudv = \iint_{D^*} \frac{1}{  2} dudv$$?

Usually, you would have to express $x=x(u, v)$ and $y=y(u,v)$ as functions of new variables and substitute them into the integrand. In your case, doing this straightforward would be somewhat challenging, so here is the trick.
Notice, that what you've calculated is not really a correct Jacobian, but the reverse one $J^{-1}$ because you need to calculate the derivatives of the old variables with respect to new ones. However, since the determinant is scalar, you can simply invert it as a fraction and put it in the integrand just like you've mentioned in your OP.
Notice, that your integrand and the Jacobian form the expression of the form:
$$f(x, y) \cdot J = (x^2+y^2)\cdot \frac{1}{2(x^2+y^2)} = \frac{1}{2}$$
There you go.

Comment:
Usually, again, you would have to express your integrand and the Jacobian in terms of new variables $x=x(u, v)$ and $y=y(u,v)$, but since this integral allows simpler substitution, it's not necessary.
